# Logging application logs in DataDog

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, datadog

Using datadog official docs, I am able to print the K8s `stdout/stderr` logs in DataDog UI, my motive is to print the app logs which are generated by spring boot application at a certain location in my pod.

Configurations done in cluster :

1. Created ServiceAccount in my cluster along with cluster role and cluster role binding
2. Created K8s secret to hold DataDog API key
3. Deployed the DataDog Agent as daemonset in all nodes

Configurations done in App :

1. Download datadog.jar and instrument it along with my app execution
2. Exposed ports 8125 and 8126
3. Added environment tags `DD_TRACE_SPAN_TAGS`, `DD_TRACE_GLOBAL_TAGS` in deployment file
4. Changed pattern in `logback.xml`
5. Added logs config in deployment file
6. Added env tags in deployment file

After doing above configurations I am able to log `stdout/stderr` logs where as I wanted to log application logs in datadog UI

If someone has done this please let me know what am I missing here.
If required, I can share the configurations as well. Thanks in advance

Comment: from your comments **"I am able to log"**, so **What's the issue here?**  And Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Using datadog too and am not aware of any configuration at datadogs end to distinguish between stdout and stderror. Also, not sure what a spring boot app writes to stdout. Usually all the logback logging is done to stdout. How can you tell, what you are seing it not from the stdout?

Comment: @abestrad, thanks for the comment, as you might know when we deploy our application in K8s cluster, we can view the logs using command ```kubectl logs -f <pod_name>```, these logs are logged in datadog UI where as I wanted to log my app logs in DataDog UI which are configured using logback.xml in path ```/var/app/logs/myapp.log```.

Comment: @FritzDuchardt using logback.xml we can print our application logs or business logic logs at a certain location in our pod, which gives better insights about the application running. I wanted to log these app logs not stdout/stderr logs in DataDogUI

Answer (score 3):

When installing Datadog in your K8s Cluster, you install a [Node Logging Agent](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#using-a-node-logging-agent) as a Daemonset with various volume mounts on the hosting nodes. Among other things, this gives Datadog access to the Pod logs at /var/log/pods and the container logs at /var/lib/docker/containers.

Kubernetes and the underlying Docker engine will only include output from stdout and stderror in those two locations (see [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#logging-at-the-node-level) for more information). Everything that is written by containers to log files residing inside the containers, will be invisible to K8s, unless more configuration is applied to extract that data, e.g. by applying the [side care container pattern](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#streaming-sidecar-container).

So, to get things working in your setup, **configure logback to log to stdout rather than /var/app/logs/myapp.log**

Also, if you don't use APM there is no need to instrument your code with the datadog.jar and do all that tracing setup (setting up ports etc).

Comment: Thanks @FritzDuchardt, configuring logback to print all logs in console did the trick. I have accepted the answer but due to low reputation it is not publicly visible.